# How to handle facebook thumbs up/like in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

Everytime someone sends a thumbs up, api.ai doesn't understand anything and my bot goes into the fallback intent. How can I handle 'thumbs up', 'thumbs down' text/emoji/image in api.ai?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really want to comment but don't have enough points to post.
API AI supports emoji https://discuss.api.ai/t/emoji-support/1061/12 
Hope you can find a clue.

Comment: i mentioned in my question that i already handled the emoji by making custom entities, the facebook like button is not an emoji it seems, when i clicked inspect element, it seems to be a svg description of some sort

Comment: thanks for the answer, i did find something about the sticker though so i ll upvote :)